# Inner RecyclerView list text not showing on header TextView through SetText

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using Nested RecyclerView with Header TextView in MainActivity that will show me the RecyclerView list Text on my Header TextView after set and get text.

Parent RecyclerView list working fine but Child RecyclerView list not showing the list text on TextView.

App crashes after clicking on Child RecyclerView list.

Here is my files:-

ParentAdapter.java

```
public class MylistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MylistAdapter.sohit> {

String[] list;
int[] img;
private Click click;
private Context context;
String listz[]={"Animals","Phone","Messenger","facebook","Whatsapp","Instagram","Contact"};
int imgz[]={R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,};



public MylistAdapter(String[] list, int[] img, Click click) {
    this.list = list;
    this.img = img;
    this.click = click;

}



@NonNull
@Override
public MylistAdapter.sohit onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    sohit sohit=new sohit(listItem);
    return sohit;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MylistAdapter.sohit holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(list[position]);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(img[position]);
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             click.onClick(holder.textView.getText().toString());
             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Click on Item: "+list[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     });

    InnerListAdapter adapter1=new InnerListAdapter(listz, imgz, context, new InnerListAdapter.Clickz() {
        @Override
        public void onClickz(String b) {
            holder.textView2.setText(b);

        }
    });

 //        recyclerView1.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.length;
}

public class sohit extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public TextView textView2;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public sohit(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.textView2=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textz);
        this.imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        this.textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        this.recyclerView=(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    }
}
public interface Click
{
    void onClick(String a);
}
}
```

ChildAdapter.java

```
public class InnerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InnerListAdapter.inner> {

String[] listz;
int[] imgz;
Context context;
private Clickz clickz;

public InnerListAdapter(String[] listz, int[] imgz,Context context,Clickz clickz) {
    this.listz = listz;
    this.imgz = imgz;
    this.context=context;
    this.clickz=clickz;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public inner onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listitemz=inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_list_item,parent,false);
    inner inner=new inner(listitemz);
    return inner;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final inner holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(listz[position]);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(imgz[position]);
    holder.linearLayout2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickz.onClickz(holder.textView.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listz.length;
}

public class inner extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
     LinearLayout linearLayout2;
    public inner(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.linearLayout2=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
        this.imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        this.textView=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
}

public interface Clickz{
    void onClickz(String b);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String list[]={"Email","Phone","Messenger","facebook","Whatsapp","Instagram","Contact"};
int img[]={R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,};


private Context context;


TextView textView;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textz);

    final RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    MylistAdapter adapter=new MylistAdapter(list, img, new MylistAdapter.Click() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String a) {
            textView.setText(a);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
}

Error Log:-

 Process: com.example.recyclerview, PID: 25309
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.recyclerview.MylistAdapter$2.onClick(MylistAdapter.java:60)
    at com.example.recyclerview.InnerListAdapter$1.onClick(InnerListAdapter.java:44)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18440)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="hello"
    android:id="@+id/textz"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>



 </LinearLayout>


list_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"/>

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>


inner_list_item.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: What error is throwing. Can you share the error logs?

Comment: this line `textView.setText(a);` in MainActivity  throwing null pointer exception, as the textview(`textz`) is not found in the activity's layout, It is inside the main recyclerview layout. Comment that line and try.

Comment: Didn't worked, App still crashes @Mohamed Ashik

Comment: Can u share the error logs or layout files(`list_item.xml`, `inner_list_item.xml`, 
`activity_main.xml`)

Comment: see the error log at the bottom of MainActivity.java file and after seen ask for me the other files.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the following layout files contains corresponding UI element(views):

list_item.xml:

`textz` (TextView),
`imageView`(ImageView),
`textView` (TextView),
`recyclerView2` (RecyclerView),
`linearLayout` (LinearLayout)

inner_list_item.xml:
`linearLayout2` (LinearLayout),
`imageView2` (ImageView),
`textView2` (TextView)

activity_main.xml:
`recyclerView` (RecyclerView),
`textz` (TextView)

EDIT:

MylistAdapter.java:

```
 InnerListAdapter adapter1=new InnerListAdapter(listz, imgz, context, new InnerListAdapter.Clickz() {
    @Override
    public void onClickz(String b) {
        holder.textView2.setText(b); // <-- causing the crash

    }
});
```

change `holder.textView2.setText(b);` ->  `holder.textView.setText(b);`
or call interface method to change textview's text in main activity
or just comment the line and check

Comment: TextView textz is only define in activity_main.xml file...how it can be in list_item.xml

Comment: i just share the xml files you can check out at the bottom of MainActivity.java file

Comment: check `MylistAdapter.java` class,    `this.textView2=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textz);`  but it is not found in its corresponding layout file

Comment: so what should i do now...i want to show the inner list name in the MainActivity Header TextView.

Comment: call the interface method -> click.onClick(b);